# Cómo puedo crear JSON usando los elementos html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

quiero crear un JSON, usando los elementos del siguiente código html

```
<div class='padre'>
    div class='hijo1'>
        demo
    </div>
    div class='hijo2'>
        <img src="foto.jpg" />
    </div>
    div class='hijo3'>
        texto
    </div>
</div>
```

El objeto JSON debe tener la siguiente forma

```
{
    "div":[
        {"class":"padre"}, 
        {"text":""},
        {
            "elements":[{
                    "div": [
                        {"class":"hijo1"},
                        {"text":"demo"},
                        {"elements":[]},    
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "div": [
                        {"class":"hijo2"},
                        {"img": [
                            "src": "foto.jpg"
                        ]},
                        {"elements":[]}    
                },
                {
                    "div": [
                        {"class":"hijo3"},
                        {"text":"texto"},
                        {"elements":[]}    
                    ]

                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

estuve probando obtener las clases de los elementos html e insertándolos en un array, usando el método each de Jquery, pero solo he podido obtener los datos de los elementos padres,mas no de los elementos hijos.

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        console.log("demo ")

        $("#btn-gen").click(function(){
            genBlock()
        })

    })

    function genBlock(cnt_block){
        var elements = []

        $("#story .block div").each(function(index){

            console.log(index)
            var class_block = $(this).attr("class")
            var class_block_content = $("." + class_block).html()
            console.log(class_block)
            console.log(class_block_content)

           /*
           $("." + class_block).each(function(){
               var class_block2 = $(this).attr("class")        
               console.log(class_block2) 
           }) */ 

           elements.push(class_block)

        }) 
        console.log(elements)
        var obj = JSON.parse(elements)
        console.log(elements)
        //console.log(subelements)
    }

    function editBlock(){
        console.log("editar block")
    } 


 </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te adjunto el código de como tendrías que modificar tu código para que haga lo que quieres.

Primero la forma que quieres obtener el json es incorrecta, ya que actualmente solo estas creando un array de string ( en este caso con las class de los div). Para crear un Json como el que quieres tienes que hacer uso de objetos.

```
    var objetoHijo = new Object();
    objetoHijo.class = $(this).attr("class")
    objetoHijo.text = $("." + objetoHijo.class).html();
    elements.push(objetoHijo)
```

En el siguiente código se crea un objeto con los atributos que quieres en tu json que son class y text, y como puedes ver en el resultado se asemeja a lo que quieres.

Y lo segundo es que si quieres obtener Padre, hijo, nietos,..etc tienes que crear una función recursiva que vaya recorriendo todo el árbol.

```
function recorrerHijo(classPadre){

    var padre = "."+classPadre;

    $(padre).children().each(function(indice, elemento){
        if (elemento.className !== ""){
            console.log("Mi padre es: "+classPadre+"  Soy el hijo: "+ elemento.className);
            recorrerHijo(elemento.className);
        }
    });
}
```

Esta función recorre todos los hijos del padre que le indiques y a su vez busca dentro de los hijos.

Uniendo los dos conceptos que te he indicado puedes obtener el Json que quieres, espero que te sirva.

```js
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        console.log("demo ")

        $("#btn-gen").click(function(){
            genBlock()
        })
  
        $("#btn-recorrer").click(function(){
            recorrerHijo("padre")
        })  

    })

 function recorrerHijo(classPadre){
 
  var padre = "."+classPadre;
  
  $(padre).children().each(function(indice, elemento){
   if (elemento.className !== ""){
    console.log("Mi padre es: "+classPadre+"  Soy el hijo: "+ elemento.className);
    recorrerHijo(elemento.className);
   }
  });
 }
    function genBlock(cnt_block){
        var elements = []
  
  recorrerHijo("padre");

        $(".padre div").each(function(index){           
   var objetoHijo = new Object();
   objetoHijo.class = $(this).attr("class")
   objetoHijo.text = $("." + objetoHijo.class).html();
   elements.push(objetoHijo)
        }) 
        console.log(elements)        
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='padre'>
    <div class='hijo1'>
        <div class="nieto1">
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class='hijo2'>
        <img src="foto.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class='hijo3'>
        texto
          <div class="nieto3">
  </div>
    </div>
 
 <button id="btn-gen">Generar</button>
  <button id="btn-recorrer">Recorrer Html</button>
</div>
```